# Regex: character set validation

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, validation

I had this regex  `^[a-zA-Z_ ,.'-]+$` for `Name` validation which was working fine. But the problem is, allowing the apostrophe raises some problems. So I encoded the apostrophe before validation.

```c#
name = name.Replace("'", "&apos;");
```

Now any valid name like `john's doe` looks like `john&apos;s doe` which can't be validate with current regex.

Now what **i want is to check** if the name contains exact the `&apos;` along with the valid character set.

**Note:** I don't want to add `&` and `;` to current character set cause this will allow `&;` as a valid name.

Comment: Why not do that the correct way? Where is your pattern stored? In some XML? Why not use it in a CData block? The `^([a-zA-Z_ ,.-]|&apos;)+$` does not look good for both people and regex engine.

Comment: What problems does allowing the apostrophe cause?  I guess you could do `^[a-zA-Z_ ,.-]+&apos;[a-zA-Z_ ,.-]+$` assuming that an apostrophe is never the first or last character.

Comment: I am using `sitecore` cms and validation runs at server side. I am not familiar with `Cdata`

Comment: Ok, does `^([a-zA-Z_ ,.-]|&apos;)+$` work?

Comment: It's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a grouping construct `(...)` or `(?:...)`:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z_ ,.-]|&apos;)+$
```

**Details**:

- `^`  - start of string
- `(?:[a-zA-Z_ ,.-]|&apos;)+` - either of the two:

  - `[a-zA-Z_ ,.-]` - a symbol from the set
  - `|` -  or
  - `&apos;` - a substring `&apos;`
- `$` - end of string.